# グーグルブラウザなのにbrowserNameでMozillaと出る

Tags: javascript, html

```
var name = navigator.appName;
console.log(name)
```

とjavascriptのコードを書いてグーグルブラウザで実行したところ、Mozilla　と表示されました。
これは正しいのでしょうか？何か間違っていますか？

Comment: 質問タイトルについて、Google Chromeにおいて `navigator.appName` を実行すると「Mozilla」と出力される、という認識で間違いないでしょうか？（手元のGoogle Chromeでは「Netscape」と出力されたので、念のため再確認したいです。）

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11、Microsoft Edge、Google Chrome、Mozilla Firefoxでは`"Netscape"`と表示されました。
歴史的な経緯で表示されるものでしょうから、特に必要が無ければこの値を参照しないことをお勧めします。

Answer (score -1):

Chrome でも "Mozilla" と表示されること自体は正しいです。そしてこれは歴史的な理由があります。

navigator.appName が返す結果は恐らく User-Agent ヘッダの値を元にしていますが、ここに Netscape のコードネームである "Mozilla" が含まれるか否かでサイトが処理を振り分けている時期がありました。
(一部のブラウザのみが優遇される)

この問題を回避するために多くのブラウザが "Mozilla (compatible)" を含めるようになり、今に至っています。

User-Agent は様々な方法で簡単に偽装できてしまうので、あまり信用できる情報ではありません。

**参考:**
[ユーザーエージェント - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)

Comment: 今回の場合、なぜ「Mozilla」と出力されるのでしょうか？`navigator.appName` が返す値は `Netscape` でなければならないはずです。